# In vimperator/pentadactyl, how can I disable almost everything?

Tags: vimperator, pentadactyl

I like the movement keys, pressing f to click links, and being able to disable pentadactyl, but I pretty much don't need anything else. How can I get my old hotkeys back?

Mostly, I'm thinking about... Ctrl+F, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, Ctrl+Shift+O (open bookmarks), which have all stopped working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth getting to know the pentadactyl/vimperator shortcuts or maps as they, arguably, offer better functionality. For e.g. the normal mode keymap `o` offers the equivalent of the firefox `Ctrl-L` and `Ctrl-O` combined - which is to say, smart completions (of bookmarks, locations, history, etc) are offered to you for tab completion.

But to answer your question - you can define some custom mappings in your `pentadactylrc` (see `:help pentadactylrc` for where yours is located) to offer you the firefox style shortcuts. For e.g.

```
" Normal Mode Mappings
nnoremap <C-f> /
nnoremap <C-w> :tabclose<CR>
nnoremap <C-c> <C-v><C-c>
nnoremap <C-v> <C-v><C-v>
nnoremap <C-x> <C-v><C-x>

" Insert Mode Mappings
inoremap <C-c> <C-v><C-c>
inoremap <C-v> <C-v><C-v>
inoremap <C-x> <C-v><C-x>
```

I forget what the other firefox shortcuts like `Ctrl-A` do but hopefully here's enough to demonstrate how you might achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use CTRL-V and then whatever you press next is passed directly to Firefox. So, CTRL-V CTRL-SHIFT-O would function as you expect.

A more complex approach would be to use the [passkeys](http://dactyl.sourceforge.net/help/pentadactyl/options.xhtml#%27passkeys%27) option to allow particular key combinations to be passed through to Firefox, though I believe in that case you would have to specify all the commands you want to use (rather than excluding just the few Pentadactyl commands you wish to retain).